# Creating a PDF file with a name taken from a database

Tags: java, pdf-generation, rad

I am new to Java.
I was able to generate a PDF with a constant name to my directory.

But my scenario is to name that PDF file by a value which I am fetching from the DB.
I'll explain my scenario below.

When I use to create that PDF with this statement, it's created with name `test.pdf`.

```
String file = "C://test.pdf";
System.out.println("creating");
Document document = new Document();
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document,
    new FileOutputStream(file));
```

But when I am trying to name that PDF with a string which I am getting from DB it's not created.

Consider if name is a column I am fetching from DB. If `name = raja` in db, I need to create that pdf file with file name as `raja.pdf`.

How would I do that?

Comment: Lol, looks like a funny problem. Would you mind to give us pieces of code so that we can really figure out what you do as we now what you wanna do now.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  And please do not type in all lower case.  The first (letter of the first) word of every sentence, the abbreviation 'PDF' and the word 'I' should all be upper case.

Comment: this does not have much to do with PDF..  was there an exception?

Answer (score 0):

According to your description:

```
String file = "C://" + name;
```

You should create a folder with write permissions tough and place it there. If its not working you should get an exception. Maybe your `System.out.println` should include the file name:

```
System.out.println("Creating: " + file);
```